# Why is Keras so reluctant to make predictions outside [-1,1]

Tags: keras

My tremendously stripped-down code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.core import  Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

inp = Input(shape=[1])
out = Dense(units=1, activation='linear')(inp)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
              optimizer='rmsprop')


x=np.array([[0]])
y=np.array([[42]])

model.fit(x,y,epochs=1000, verbose=False)
prediction = model.predict(x)

print(prediction)
```

It outputs `[[1.0091327]]`

The model has exactly two parameters: a weight and bias for its 1-dimensional output.  And the weight doesn't matter because `x` is always 0.  This should be pretty easy to train.

If instead of `42` I use `0.42` or `-0.42` for y it works fine (4.2 and -42 do not).  So I figure there must be some sort of normalization *somewhere* softly compressing either outputs or biases toward [-1,1].

Does anyone know what this normalization is and how to turn it off?

(Before anyone tells me I shouldn't use neural nets for something this silly, my real code does a lot more.  I wrote this stripped version for clarity and debugging.)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no built-in normalization, that is the users job.

What you are seeing is the "why" we use normalization, without it the optimization problem is a lot harder, after I run the example you can see that the loss does not go anywhere close to zero and stays around 41.

If you make some changes like using a mean squared error loss and running this example for 50K epochs, then you get it to converge to a zero loss and it outputs 42 as expected.

A common beginner's mistake is to look at the prediction without looking first at the training loss, as the loss is high it will means the predictions will be wrong.